# BigQuery: Load Data into EU Dataset from GCS

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In the past I have successfully loaded data into US-hosted BigQuery datasets from CSV data in US-hosted GCS buckets.  We since decided to move our BigQuery data to the EU and I created a new dataset with this region selected on it.  I have successfully populated those of our tables small enough to be uploaded from my machine at home.  But two tables are far too large for this so I would like to load them from files in GCS.  I have tried doing this from both a US-hosted GCS bucket and an EU-hosted GCS bucket (thinking that `bq load` might not like to cross regions) but the load fails every time.  Below is the error detail I'm getting from the `bq` command line (500, Internal Error).  Does anyone know a reason why this might be happening?

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "load": {
      "destinationTable": {
        "datasetId": "######", 
        "projectId": "######", 
        "tableId": "test"
      }, 
      "schema": {
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "test_col", 
            "type": "INTEGER"
          }
        ]
      }, 
      "sourceFormat": "CSV", 
      "sourceUris": [
        "gs://######/test.csv"
      ]
    }
  }, 
  "etag": "######", 
  "id": "######", 
  "jobReference": {
    "jobId": "######", 
    "projectId": "######"
  }, 
  "kind": "bigquery#job", 
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/######", 
  "statistics": {
    "creationTime": "1445336673213", 
    "endTime": "1445336674738", 
    "startTime": "1445336674738"
  }, 
  "status": {
    "errorResult": {
      "message": "An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.", 
      "reason": "internalError"
    }, 
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.", 
        "reason": "internalError"
      }
    ], 
    "state": "DONE"
  }, 
  "user_email": "######"
}
```

Comment: Looking into what you've provided it seems okay. I don't see what could be wrong here. The fact you get an internal error seems to mean you don't have quota issues. If you're certain you have at least read on the Google Cloud Storage object (which could block you), I would suggest reposting this on Stack Overflow, with the job ID. We have BigQuery engineers who look up the newest questions tagged with BigQuery and they answer them :). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

After searching through other related questions on StackOverflow I eventually realised that I had set my GCS bucket region to `EUROPE-WEST-1` and not the multi-region `EU` location. Things are now working as expected.